# Best way mapper data object Android Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, mapping

I have a problem that is mapping data objects to data objects but prioritizing performance. I just knew the right way, but it's not performance.

```
fun SignInResponse?.toSignInInfo() = SignInInfo(
    id = this?.id.orEmpty(),
    email = this?.email.orEmpty(),
    name = this?.name.orEmpty(),
)
```

This function will be called when I get a response.

Comment: What you looking for? Cleaning up the code? Other ways to map one object to another? It's not clear the question for me sorry.